# Cant see plugin, user and project lists in rundeck

Tags: docker-compose, rundeck

Hey guys im just installed rundeck 3.4.9 via docker-compose and after it i cant see the list of installed plugins, the page is refreshing endlessly - same with project list and with user list.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
    version: '3'

services:
    rundeck:
        image: rundeck/rundeck:3.4.9
        tty: true
        volumes:
          - data:/home/rundeck/server/data
        ports:
          - 4440:4440

volumes:
    data:
```

here is what i see in browser:

[image: loading plugins]

here what i see in docker-compose logs:

[image: logs]

so no errors here, how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: Your instance is behind a proxy server? I tested your docker-compose directly, it works.

Comment: yes, its behind a proxy

Answer (score 0):

In your `docker-compose` definition add the `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL` with the proxy-defined URL for your Rundeck instance and `RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED` with a `true` value.

I made a basic example using NGINX as a reverse proxy.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  rundeck:
    image: rundeck/rundeck:3.4.9
    ports:
      - 4440:4440
    environment:
      RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL: http://your_proxy_exit_url_for_rundeck
      RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED: "true"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    ports:
    - 80:80
```

(NGINX conf file referenced on the `volumes` section):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name rundeck-cl;

    # default rundeck location is the root 
    location / {
        # took from default rundeck conf
        proxy_pass http://rundeck:4440;
     }
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/docker.html#basic).